# Subtracting Time using timediff

Tags: mysql

help. I have this query in mysql. What it does is combine fields from three tables. One field (Duration (h)) it subtracts the end time and start time. May time data is in the form of time only and not date time. So I decided to use timediff function. This runs well for time within the same day. But not time differences like 00:00 - 23:30; in this case I get the answer -23.5. What can I do to correct this. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT `tblproductiondata`.`productionDay` , `tbllinestoppagecategories`.`category` , `tblshifts`.`ID` , `tblstoppagedescriptions`.`endTime` , `tblstoppagedescriptions`.`startTime` , IFNULL( ROUND( `tblstoppagedescriptions`.`duration(mins)` /60, 2 ) , ROUND( (
TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( `tblstoppagedescriptions`.`endTime` , `tblstoppagedescriptions`.`startTime` ) ) /3600 ) , 2 )
) AS `Duration (h)`
FROM (
`tbllinestoppagecategories`
INNER JOIN `tblstoppagereasons` ON `tbllinestoppagecategories`.`categoryID` = `tblstoppagereasons`.`stoppagecategory`
)
INNER JOIN (
`tblshifts`
INNER JOIN (
`tblproductiondata`
INNER JOIN `tblstoppageDescriptions` ON `tblproductiondata`.`productionID` = `tblstoppagedescriptions`.`prodDate`
) ON `tblshifts`.`ID` = `tblproductiondata`.`shiftName`
) ON `tblstoppageReasons`.`resID` = `tblstoppagedescriptions`.`stoppageReason`
WHERE (
(
(
`tbllinestoppagecategories`.`category`
) <> "Changeover Maintenance Activities"
)
)
ORDER BY `tblproductiondata`.`productionDay` ASC
```

Comment: what fields contain the start date and the end date?

Comment: `tblstoppagedescriptions`.`startTime` and `tblstoppagedescriptions`.`endTime`. I am dealing with times only in these fields

Comment: those two fields are for the time, but do you store the date (the day) in some other field? In order to compute the time difference you have to know the two dates, too.

Comment: I have a one-to-many relationship between tblproductiondata table (which contains the date) and tblstoppagedescriptions table which contains the times. You see, i want to store problems that occurred on a machine on a given day. So the times in tblstoppagedescriptions table are attributed to particular days in tblproductiondata table

Answer (score 0):

try

```
TIME_TO_SEC(
    TIMEDIFF( 
        CONCAT(tblproductiondata.productionDay, ' ', tblstoppagedescriptions.endTime),  
        CONCAT(tblproductiondata.productionDay, ' ', `tblstoppagedescriptions`.`startTime`)
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Arilla, the query is still producing the same results. I have realised that even after concatenating the result will be the same because of the way the tblproductiondata table is structured. a given production day say 24/12/2013 is from 24/12/2013 06:00 to 25/12/2013 06:00. Meaning even if I concatenate productionDay with the time, the timediff function dealing with times (00:00 and 23:30) will still produce the same result since the date is the same. I will just change the times to datetime format. Thank you for your help I wouldnt have realised this without it.

Comment: Say, I have replaced the data from time to datetime. The timediff function is now giving null as a result. Any ideas why

Comment: Hello I think I finally got it the problem was the data itself I changed all the field to datetime and entered new data.